# Apache authentication fails with require ldap-group

Tags: active-directory, apache-2.4, ldap, authentication, authorization

I have been trying to tie apache on a windows server to our active directory server for authentication and authorization.

In order to test it, I have been trying the "ldap-status" handler, with the following parameters

```
<Location "/ldap-status">
    SetHandler ldap-status

    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthName "LDAP Status"
    LDAPReferrals off
    AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative on
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://1.2.3.4:389/cn=Users,dc=XXX,dc=example,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=person)" NONE
    AuthLDAPGroupAttribute member
    AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on
    AuthLDAPMaxSubGroupDepth 0
    AuthLDAPBindDN xxx
    AuthLDAPBindPassword xxx
    Require ldap-group "cn=TEST GROUP,cn=Users,dc=XXX,dc=example,dc=com"
</Location>
```

Up to this point, if I remove `Require ldap-group` and replace it with `Require valid-user`, it works correctly, but not if I restore the group requirement.

From what I can see from the AD server using powershell, the group exists and it has a `member` attribute which lists the DN of all members; based on this I set `AuthLDAPGroupAttribute` to `member` and `AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN` to `on`.

I am sure my user is in the group for which I am requiring the check, however In apache error log there is only this record, which does not really help understanding the cause:

> [Mon Apr 27 14:52:08.023952 2020] [authz_core:error] [pid 13168:tid 2072] [client 10.0.1.45:59690] AH01631: user mtassinari: authorization failure for "/ldap-status":

What can I do to correct the configuration in order to understand why "require ldap-group" fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I have been able to make it work by splitting authentication and authorization with alias, like this:

```
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap my-ldap>
    AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative on
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://1.2.1.4:389/cn=Users,dc=XXX,dc=example,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=person)" NONE
    AuthLDAPBindDN xxx
    AuthLDAPBindPassword xxx
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<AuthzProviderAlias ldap-group ldap-group-test "cn=TEST GROUP,cn=Users,dc=XXX,dc=example,dc=com">
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://1.2.1.4:389/cn=Users,dc=XXX,dc=example,dc=com" NONE
    AuthLDAPBindDN xxx
    AuthLDAPBindPassword xxx
    AuthLDAPGroupAttribute member
    AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on
    AuthLDAPMaxSubGroupDepth 0
</AuthzProviderAlias>

<Location "/ldap-status">
    SetHandler ldap-status
    LDAPReferrals off

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "LDAP Status"
    AuthBasicProvider my-ldap
    Require ldap-group-test
</Location>
```

I **think** the key difference here is the `AuthLDAPURL`, which in the authorization provider is without any filter, it just doesn't feel right to have to repeat common configuration parameters to make it work.

Comment: Thank you for that example - I couldn't get it to work by removing the quotes as mentioned in the other answer. When working with the alias I also made the error to use `require ldap-group <alias>` instead of `require <alias>`, which doesn't work of course. When setting logging to `LogLevel warn authz_core:trace8 authnz_ldap:trace8` this solution is the only one, where Apache logs "... require group: testing for group membership ..." into the error.log

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into this issue it was specifically that I assumed I should quote the distinguished group name (since it contained spaces), however you specifically should not use quotes when it comes to Require ldap-group, see reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#reqgroup

Once I removed the quotes I was able to use ldap-group without issue and without using aliases.